# How can I remove the left and right space from first & last images?

Tags: html, css

[My site](http://jeffreydowellphotography.com/things/) has a slideshow with white space in between all images; however, I would like to remove the white space on the **left** for the **first image**, and the white space on the **right** of the **last image**, so it bleeds off of the page. However its not removing what i want.

what I'm using:

```
.collection-type-gallery #slideshowWrapper .slide img {
background-color: white !important; 
margin: 0px 6px;

.slide:first-child {
margin-left: 0px;}

.slide:last-child {
margin-right: 0px;}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.collection-type-gallery #slideshowWrapper .slide:first-child img
```

instead of

```
.collection-type-gallery #slideshowWrapper .slide img .slide:first-child
```